# postgresql: How to write IN clause for composite conditions?

Tags: postgresql

A normal `IN` clause is written like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM x
WHERE
x.field IN (100, 200, 300, 400)
```

However, this is only one field. I need to write a query where I do look ups over 2 fields.

That is: Pseudo Code -->

```
SELECT * 
FROM x
WHERE
IN (x.field1 = 100 AND x.field2 = 'someString', x.field1 = 200 AND x.field2 = 'someOtherString')
```

What is a convenient way to write such query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57223/1

```
select * from q
where 
  (x,y) in ((1,2),(5,5))
```